# USB Media filesystem problem

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, usb

My USB is not detected recently, I tried `mount`, `fdisk`, `dd`, `gparted`, `mkfs.vfat`

```
:~# tail -f /var/log/syslog
Oct 27 12:54:29 mohammad-Inspiron-N5110 kernel: [18843.105772] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Oct 27 12:54:29 mohammad-Inspiron-N5110 kernel: [18843.107485] scsi31 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
Oct 27 12:54:29 mohammad-Inspiron-N5110 mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 13: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:0b:00.0/usb3/3-2"
Oct 27 12:54:29 mohammad-Inspiron-N5110 mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 13 was not an MTP device
Oct 27 12:54:30 mohammad-Inspiron-N5110 kernel: [18844.104912] scsi 31:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USBest   USB2FlashStorage 0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Oct 27 12:54:30 mohammad-Inspiron-N5110 kernel: [18844.107132] sd 31:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Oct 27 12:54:30 mohammad-Inspiron-N5110 kernel: [18844.108857] sd 31:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk

:~# mount /dev/sdb /mnt
mount: no medium found on /dev/sdb

:~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders, total 1250263728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00051f45

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   200000094    99999023+  83  Linux
/dev/sda2       200001534  1250263039   525130753    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       200001536  1250263039   525130752   83  Linux

:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1
dd: opening ‘/dev/sdb’: No medium found

:~# gparted /dev/sdb
======================
libparted : 2.3
======================
Error opening /dev/sdb: No medium found

:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 09da:000a A4 Tech Co., Ltd Optical Mouse Opto 510D
Bus 003 Device 013: ID 1307:0163 Transcend Information, Inc. 256MB/512MB/1GB Flash Drive

:~# mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb
mkfs.vfat 3.0.14 (23 Jan 2023)
/dev/sdb: No medium found
```

testdisk also returns :

```
:~# testdisk /dev/sdb
TestDisk 6.13, Data Recovery Utility, November 2011
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Unable to open file or device /dev/sdb
```

Any idea? Any suggestion?

Comment: install `testdisk` and us it.however kernel says sdb doesn't exists sdb.

Comment: Dear @MohsenPahlevanzadeh , i had tried that too, here is the result :~# testdisk /dev/sdb
TestDisk 6.13, Data Recovery Utility, November 2011
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Unable to open file or device /dev/sdb

Comment: Same problem here! :(

Comment: Are you sure the drive still gets assigned to `/dev/sdb`? The kernel log from `dmesg` might also have some clues... (You probably want to start with something like `dmesg | tail -50` to see recent messages, just after plugging in the drive)

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, you do not need to use "ChipGenius", the only thing you need is the VendorId and ProductId of your device then look for the chip used by your device using an online web site that gather this kind of information such as  http://flashboot.ru/iflash/
To get vendor id and product id just use `lsusb`.
Example:
`Bus 004 Device 012: ID 1f75:0917 Innostor Technology Corporation`
In this example, vid == 1f75 and pid == 0917.

About the tool needed to reprogram the chip, I am now investigating to get one working using wine, usb support is still experimental but some work was done: http://wiki.winehq.org/USB

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and could fix my USB using this steps:

- use the program "ChipGenius" to know the type of the control chip used (Windows required)
- search in Google for a tool that can recover/fix/format my USB specifying the control chip
- now the USD disk is detected, and i can format/partition it!

Useful links:

- http://usb-fix.blogspot.com.es/
- http://www.flashdrive-repair.com/2012/12/how-to-repair-usb-flash-drive-in-three.html (i found this link after fixing my USB disk)
- http://www.myusbtools.com/2013/06/chipgenius-v301-ultimate-master-of-usb.html

Comment: In my case, the info i need was "innostor" and "is916". And i found this tool http://flashboot.ru/files/file/380/

Comment: thanks for your answer, is there any Linux tools too?

Comment: Sorry @MohammadRafiee but i have only found Windows tools

Answer (score -1):

Something similar happened to me with a WD drive.

Did you mess with any of the config files on the drive? During experimentation, I was deleting things like "autorun.inf" from my drive and became totally locked out.

I used fdisk to create partitions on the drive, which made Linux happy.

You didn't specify if you have data on the drive that you are trying to save, so this might not work for you.

Comment: Deleting files on a drive should not make it inaccessible.

The OP already mentioned that fdisk gives an error on the device

Comment: @Gert Sorry if I missed where OP says that fdisk gives an error. However, I still can't see where OP says that. Also, deleting autorun.inf on my WD drive did make it inaccessible until I repartitioned.